# Transform list of data frames to single data frame with many columns using do.call does not work within loop in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, do.call

Ι have a list of .txt files that have data for specific models and for specific months. I read them all in a loop and they are stored in a list, as it is shown in the following code, which works fine!

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("reshape2") 
library("plyr")
library("data.table")
library("gridExtra")
library("varhandle")
library("lattice")
library("rowr")
library("lubridate")
library("hydroTSM")
#
####################################   
########### MONTHLY LOOP ###########
####################################
#
mons = c("OCT","NOV","DEC","JAN","FEB","MAR")
#
#####################
##### LOAD CMIP5 ####
#####################
for (i in 1:length(mons)) {
  #
  print(mons[i])
  setwd("/mnt/.../cmip5/")
  # Load all files
  files = list.files(pattern="*.txt", full.names=F)
  files
  # Read all files as data frames
  dat = lapply(files, function(x){
    read.table(x, header=F, sep=",")
  })
  # Rename files 
  names(dat) = files
  # Get all MONTHS ###LOOP HERE###
  dat_regA_cmip5 = dat[grepl(mons[i], names(dat))]
  length(dat_regA_cmip5)
  #
}
```

However, I want to transform the list into a single data frame with many columns and I do this with:

```
cmip5 = do.call(cbind, dat_regA_cmip5)
```

When I apply the above line with do.call on single data frame (dat_regA_cmip5: selected manually for a single month, hence not inside the mons loop) it works fine. But when I put it inside the mons loop I get the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 19
```

Note: the loop runs for OCT, NOV and DEC, but stops on JAN

Answer (score 1):

If the datasets have different number of rows, then it is better to use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
cmip5 = do.call(cbind.fill, c(dat_regA_cmip5, fill = NA))
```

---

A reproducible example

```
df<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(c = 1:2, d = 3:4)
lst1 <- list(df, df2)
do.call(cbind.fill, c(lst1, fill = NA))
#  a b  c  d
#1 1 1  1  3
#2 2 2  2  4
#3 3 3 NA NA
```

With regular `cbind`, it returns the error

```
do.call(cbind, lst1)
```

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :    arguments imply
>   differing number of rows: 3, 2